# Porting an C++ code application from Solaris to Linux and real time headers issues

Tags: qt4, solaris, porting

Please help, The tools that I am using are kdevelop and qt4. On my main.cpp have errors, for example;

```
Error: sys/procset.h: No such files or directory
Error: sys/priocntl.h: No such files or directory
Error: sys/tspriocntl.h: No such files or directory
Error: sys/rtpriocntl.h: No such files or directory
In function 'int main(int. char**)':
Error: 'pcparms_t' was not declared in this scope
Error: expected ';' before 'pcparms'
Error: 'rtparms_t' was not declared in this scope
Error: 'rtparmsp' was not declared in this scope
Error: 'pcinfo_t' was not declared in this scope
Error: expected ';' before 'pcinfo'
Error: 'rtinfo_t' was not declared in this scope
Error: 'rtinfop' was not declared in this scope
warning: unused variable 'lret'
warning: unused variable 'priority'
...
...
...
*Exited with Status:2 *
```

I can't find real time those headers on my Centos 5 Linux.  Plus, I don't know the equivalence of those above headers for Linux.  I know I have to add an If statement for Solaris and Linux for the include headers, and I don't know which headers will be included on the if/else statement.

When I remove headers by comment them out the real time headers and function for realtime function for solaris, I get it to run.

```
//pcparms_t pcparms;
//rtparms_t *rtparmsp;
//pcinfo_t pcinfo;
//rtinfo_t *rtinfop;
```

My problem is what are the real time headers and functions for Linux or equivalent to Linux. My application code is a mix between c++ and qt4.  On the side of qt4 is their a need to use Real Time functions? On the c++ from Solaris do I need real time functions? If yes, where can I find them or what are they call and where do I place them?

Comment: Did you do a `locate procset.h` or `find / | grep "procset.h"` to find out where that file is?

Answer (score 1):

This is not really a QT related question but more of a porting Solaris->Linux question.

```
sys/procset.h
sys/priocntl.h
sys/tspriocntl.h
sys/rtpriocntl.h
```

Those files are all Solaris specific system calls. They are part of **priocntlset** - generalized process scheduler control.

From the manpage

```
priocntlset(2)           System Calls           priocntlset(2)

NAME
       priocntlset - generalized process scheduler control

SYNOPSIS
       #include <sys/types.h>
       #include <sys/procset.h>
       #include <sys/priocntl.h>
       #include <sys/rtpriocntl.h>
       #include <sys/tspriocntl.h>
       #include <sys/iapriocntl.h>
       #include <sys/fsspriocntl.h>
       #include <sys/fxpriocntl.h>

       long priocntlset(procset_t *psp, int cmd, /* arg */ ...);

DESCRIPTION
       The priocntlset() function changes the scheduling properties of running
       processes. priocntlset() has the same functions as the priocntl() func-
       tion,  but  a more general way of specifying the set of processes whose
       scheduling properties are to be changed.

NOTES
    Due to the lack of a priocntl() system call on Linux and FreeBSD...
```

The way in which processes are handled between Solaris and Linux is different. Both systems are variants of Unix, but the specific system calls you are looking for do not have a Linux equivalent. Basically priocntlset is used to (re)schedule processes. I am not up to date on the latest Linux Kernel, or what schedulers are available anymore, but any good book on a 2.6 (or 2.4) Kernel will have a section on scheduling with examples.

A good place to start on a Linux machine would be `man syscalls`.